# How come I can't install Dolphin or Krusader file managers from the Software Center?

Tags: 16.04, filemanager, dolphin, support, krusader

I'm using 16.04. I can install other apps but not the file managers. Terminal commands won't work either. Are these two applications no longer supported?

EDIT: Here are my terminal logs:

sudo apt-get update: https://pastebin.com/B2dCt2Yg

sudo apt-get install krusader: https://pastebin.com/iZWvZrTh

sudo apt-get install dolphin: https://pastebin.com/Y14UEbwt

Comment: What are the error messages when in terminal? Please [edit] and post them in its entirety.

Comment: Update your question with output of `sudo apt-get update` (update software indexes) and `sudo apt-get install krusader dolphin --simulate` (simulate installation of Krusader and Dolphin).

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I updated my question as requested.

Comment: Do not use pastebin here; pasting the text directly in your question works just fine.

Comment: That would be a lot of text though. Won't it take up srveral pages?